# How to display image returned from fetch() method - react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch

I have the following code to retrieve an image from an API

```
await fetch('https://example.com/api/user/fileaccess', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'token':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    },
    body:  JSON.stringify({"applicantid": xxxx, "user_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxx","fileid":xxxxx}),
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

The request was completed and i got log in my console.

> {"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId":
>   "xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxx", "offset": 0, "size": 953328}},
>   "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId":
>   "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx", "offset": 0, "size": 953328}},
>   "headers": {"map": {"cache-control": "max-age=2592000", "connection":
>   "Keep-Alive", "content-type": "image/jpeg", "date": "Tue, 04 Feb 2020
>   10:34:14 GMT", "expires": "Thu, 05 Mar 2020 10:34:14 GMT",
>   "keep-alive": "timeout=5, max=100", "pragma": "public", "server":
>   "Apache", "transfer-encoding": "chunked"}}, "ok": true, "status": 200,
>   "statusText": undefined, "type": "default", "url":
>   "https://example.com/api/user/fileaccess"}

My question is, How to display this data as an image in my app? Is it possible to convert a base64 from this data?

Comment: Is that Url has your Image?

Comment: Yes, I can see it in postman

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract it into json or text or some other data before you can do anything with the response.

As per [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), A basic fetch request is really simple to set up. Have a look at the following code:

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((myJson) => {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
```

So, modify your code as below :

```
fetch('https://example.com/api/user/fileaccess', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'token':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    },
    body:  JSON.stringify({"applicantid": xxxx, "user_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxx","fileid":xxxxx}),
  })
.then(response => response.json())
.then((result) => {
     console.log("Your intended result is: " , result)
});
```

The `response.json()` is added just assuming the server is returning a JSON data.
If not, you can try the below methods too based on your server implementation.

> arrayBuffer()
>   blob()
>   json()
>   text()
>   formData()

Answer (score 0):

If that's the image URL you can go ahead as follows
Store image in your state

```
this.setState({image:res.url})
```

and then `<Image source={{uri:this.state.image}}/>`